# InnoDB composite auto-increment based on 2 columns (prefix & date)

Tags: date, innodb, auto-increment, reset

I'm working on a customer service queue system, where I have a single alphabetic character to indicate service type (A..Z). I want tickets numbers to be generated in A1, B2 etc. format. So each series should depend on the letters A..Z and start counting from 1.

Achieving this should be fairly easy I assume using triggers??

Now comes the complex part. I want the auto-increment counters to reset and start counting from 1 for each passing day. In effect, every day, the tickets should start issuing from A1 through Axxx.

What can I do achieve this effect?

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 0):

What if there are gaps in the numbers?  If you don't what that, you should not not use `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  And there are several other reasons not to trust `AUTO_INCREMENT` even if you could get it to do like you want.

What programming language are you using?  Do the coding there.  And be sure to use "transactions" to cover various end-cases.

Comment: Rick - what do you mean by gaps in the numbers here? If the composite auto-increment is progressing sequentially, why would there be gaps in the numbers? Thanks,.

Comment: Sure, simple, normal, non-crash usage leads to gap-less AIs.  But... DELETE, REPLACE, ROLLBACK, deadlock, INSERT IGNORE with dup key, Server crash, etc.  I don't have the complete list off the top of my head.  There are a lot of ways that you can end up with gaps in an AI.